# Burp Suite can not intercept the wget and curl HTTP request

Tags: curl

I use Burp Suite as proxy listen 127.0.0.1:8080,
and I also set the HTTP Proxy as 127.0.0.1:8080.

now Burp Suite can intercept all the browsers(eg. firefox, safari, chrome), and application(eg. dictionary ) on my Mac:
[image]

---

but can not intercept the `wget` and `curl`'s request.

such as:

```
curl www.apple.com
```

Isn't curl and wget using HTTP protocol requests?

---

**EDIT-01**

1. Why I set macOS preferences HTTP Proxy to `127.0.0.1:8080`, all the browsers and applications will use this Proxy by default? I did not set in each browser.
2. Why curl and wget do not use the proxy by default? even I set --proxy still not work.

```
wget www.cloud123.com --proxy 127.0.0.1:8080
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the manpages for [`wget`](https://www.gnu.org/software/wget/manual/wget.html) and [`curl`](https://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html) you'd notice that `curl` has [`--proxy`](https://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html#-x), but `wget` doesn't. Both do use environment variables, even with the same names:

> **[Wget: 8.1 Proxies](https://www.gnu.org/software/wget/manual/wget.html#Proxies)**
>
> Wget supports proxies for both HTTP and FTP retrievals. The standard
> way to specify proxy location, which Wget recognizes, is using the
> following environment variables:
>
> - `http_proxy`
> - `https_proxy`
>
> If set, the `http_proxy` and `https_proxy` variables should contain
> the URLs of the proxies for HTTP and HTTPS connections respectively.

> [**CURL: ENVIRONMENT**](https://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html#httpproxy)
>
> Using an environment variable to set the proxy has the same effect as
> using the `-x`, `--proxy` option.
>
> - `http_proxy [protocol://]<host>[:port]` Sets the proxy server to use for HTTP.
> - `HTTPS_PROXY [protocol://]<host>[:port]` Sets the proxy server to use for HTTPS.

This means that, in addition to [*ropnop's* Example 1 - Proxying curl and wget](https://blog.ropnop.com/proxying-cli-tools/#example-1---proxying-curl-and-wget),

> ```
> export http_proxy=localhost:8080
> export https_proxy=localhost:8080
> curl example.com
> wget -O /dev/null example.com
>
> ## or ##
>
> http_proxy=localhost:8080 https_proxy=localhost:8080 curl example.com
> http_proxy=localhost:8080 https_proxy=localhost:8080 wget -O /dev/null example.com
> ```

you can also use

```
curl --proxy localhost:8080 example.com
```

but the same syntax doesn't work with Wget.

Answer (score 0):

For curl and wget you can use the `http_proxy` and `https_proxy` environment variables.  See [Proxying and Intercepting CLI Tools](https://blog.ropnop.com/proxying-cli-tools/#example-1---proxying-curl-and-wget) maybe you set one but not the other?

Please share how you set the proxy that your browsers use.

Answer (score 0):

Your browsers and applications automatically use your system proxy settings, which you have set.

`curl` and `wget` do not automatically use your system settings; you need to set them manually by looking up these settings their documentation.